# Sitecore Powershell - Get all items under buckets

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-query, powershell

I am trying to see if I can traverse through every node in a `bucket` and get all its items using `PSE`. All I am able to get is only the root bucket folder.

I tried all the below options with no luck.

```
 $allItems = Get-ChildItem  -Recurse master: -Query "/sitecore/system/Modules/Redirect Module/Redirects/Sites/Url//*[@@templatename ='Redirect Url']" -language en

  $allItems = Get-ChildItem -Path  -Recurse master: -ID "{A6BA7A2F-3C77-4655-B022-CC718BDB0B6E}"

  $everythingUnderRedirects = Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/system/Modules/Redirect Module/Redirects/Sites/Url//*[@@templatename ='Redirect Url']" -Language en
```

It returns me only the root bucket folder  (the year folder 2016, 2017, etc)

Comment: What's the data structure? It's not entirely clear which items you want to return. I can see you using both Get-Item and Get-ChildItem with the same query. Your Powershell commands are also a little strange, some places you give a -Path parameter without declaring it, and in the 2nd example you declare it but follow it with -Recurse before you give it a value.

Comment: @JamesWalfordas as i said in my question.... i tried 3 different queries..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Find-Item command-let instead of Get-Item

```
$criteria = @(
  @{ Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = "Redirect Url"; }, 
  @{ Filter = "DescendantOf"; Value = (Get-Item "master:/sitecore/system/Modules/Redirect Module/Redirects/Sites/Url/"); }
)

$props = @{
    Index = "sitecore_master_index"
    Criteria = $criteria
}

$allItems = Find-Item @props
```

Comment: thank you.. that did it..